# Subtract working days from a date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'd like to use a Javascript within my zapier.com-zap. Here is what I am trying to do for five consecutive days now:

I have a **date** (whatever custom format you need), need to **subtract two working days** from it and output it to DD-MM-YYYY using Javascript. Sounds really simple, but I don't get it to work.

I hope someone out there can help me with this! Thank you very much.

*I forgot to mention an essential thing, sorry. If the result is a Sunday or Saturday I need the date of the last working day (Friday).*

Comment: Are you willing to use external libraries? If so, Moment.js would make this a really simple process (`moment(date).subtract(2, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')`).

Comment: Are "working days" significant somehow, or can we just go back two days from any given date? (Example: Skip weekends or no? b/c that complicates the problem a bit)

Comment: I forgot to mention an essential thing, sorry. If the result is a Sunday or Saturday I need the date of the last working day (Friday).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I appreciate that a lot!

Comment: You are expected to at least attempt some code, this is not a free code writing service. There are plenty of similar questions here and much information on the web about adding and subtracting days from a date, as well as determining the day of the week.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use external libraries, [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) is a really popular tool for parsing and modifying JavaScript dates and would make this really simple:

### Example 1: Subtract 2 Days and Format

```js
var date = new Date(),
    formatted = moment(date).subtract(2, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');

document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = formatted;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
This example takes today's date (<span id="date"></span>), subtracts 2 days from it,
and then displays it below in the desired format (DD-MM-YYYY):

<p id="example"></p>
```

### Example 2: Subtract 2 *Working* Days and Format

If by *working days* you mean Monday to Friday, all you'd need to do here is determine whether the day held in your `date` variable was a Monday or Tuesday, then adjust the value passed in to MomentJS's `subtract` method accordingly. We can do this using [MomentJS's *get day of week* function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/):

```js
var date = new Date(),
    formatted, daysToSubtract;

switch (moment(date).day()) {
    // Sunday = 3 days
    case 0:
      daysToSubtract = 3;
      break;
    // Monday and Tuesday = 4 days
    case 1:
    case 2:
      daysToSubtract = 4;
      break;
    // Subtract 2 days otherwise.
    default:
      daysToSubtract = 2;
      break;
}


formatted = moment(date).subtract(daysToSubtract, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');

document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = formatted;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
This example takes today's date (<span id="date"></span>), subtracts 2 working days (Monday to Friday) from it,
and then displays it below in the desired format (DD-MM-YYYY):

<p id="example"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @James Donnelly that momentjs is awesome, here is how you can achieve your task without using an extra library.  I created this helper function to do exactly what you're asking.  Just pass in your date and however many days you want to add/subtract to it (-2 in your case).

```
function addDaysToDate(date, days)
{
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    var dd = result.getDate();
    var mm = result.getMonth() + 1; // January starts at 0.
    var yyyy = result.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10)
    {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    if (mm < 10)
    {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }

    return dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
}
```